# Is the tag [wtf] acceptable?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

On StackOverflow, there are currently [43 questions tagged "wtf."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wtf) I found them by noticing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595782/inheritance-and-hidden-overloads) on the main Questions page. I retagged that question, removing "wtf," because it seems like that's not really a useful tag.

Or is it? Is there a rationale need for the tag, "wtf?" If not, should it be stricken in edits?

Comment: WTF = Why the face?

Comment: Related: There are also `[weird]`, `[weird-behaviour]`, `[strange]`, `[strange-behaviour]`, `[strange-errors]`, `[odd-behavior]`, `[odd-behaviour]`, `[oddness]`, `[odd-requirments]`, `[odd-syntax]` annnnnd `[wild-goose-chase]`. lol

Comment: I've often wanted to tag something `[wild-goose-chase]` ...

Comment: nope, not a good tag

Comment: I've often wanted to retag a question [head-in-yer-arse]

Comment: If `head-in-yer-arse` gets through, I want `arrrrrrrgh` (Only with 7 r's. No other variation will be tolerated.)

Comment: ... and `didnt-you-ask-that-an-hour-ago`

Comment: @Pekka: Gaaahh I hate those! I responded to one a week ago saying "please don't duplicate your own questions" and he replied, "I had to because the old question got closed before I got a good answer."  ***headdesk***

Comment: @aargh, ***fist*** -> ***his_head*** works better.

Answer (score 17):

I was going to say no, but [now I have to say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834179/wtf-is-wtf-in-webkit-code-base)

## [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834179/wtf-is-wtf-in-webkit-code-base)

<sub>Be careful when retagging people.</sub>

Comment: I almost left [wtf] on this question, but considering had that been the only use of the tag that it would've been deleted by the new 6-months-1-use-means-delete-tag script, I didn't really see the value in keeping it.  (Retagged [web-template-framework] though, but that'll probably get deleted by the script in 6 months or so.)

Comment: What about this question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2029862/revisions is it related to the web template framework? They seem to be similar components but I can't quite tell.  also this one http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2591820/revisions

Comment: @The Cat ah ok. *`[web-template-framework]`* is a suitable tag. Do you know anything about it to consider if the two questions I linked above pertain to the web template framework?

Comment: WTF is a C++ library, not Obj-C, but I don't use Obj-C.  As always, fix it if you think it's wrong. @ear

Comment: @The Cat I'll leave it alone. I don't know anything about WTF. Do you know if `webkit` is a good (popular) tag for WTF though? KennyTM retagged http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834179/wtf-is-wtf-in-webkit-code-base as `[webkit]`

Comment: [webkit] appears perfectly fine for this question, as for other Web Template Framework questions... well, I've just never seen any.  Deal with that when they exist (or someone finds them).  @ear

Answer (score 3):

In the context of SF where I'm much more in-tune, I would edit it out.  We strive for a line of professionalism in the sites that I think this crosses.  It should be possible to get that point across in the proper wording of the question.

*meta* on the other hand...

Answer (score 3):

It could be (write-to-file, windowed-time-facility(apple), etc.), depending on the context. Sure, the tag is ambiguous but then again that doesn't mean it hasn't been used - AOL added a "WTF" button ("What's this for?") in one of their aim-clients once. If it's just somebody venting some frustration, I'd say it's best to remove it.

Comment: Kinda like the "Boss" button that NBC put on the media player on their 2010 Olympics site.  Hit it and it turned the player into an image of Excel 2007 :)

Comment: "Wow Text File", "Warcraft Text File"..

Answer (score 2):

While it's a legitimate term to describe a situation when you *really, really*
 don't know how the hell this piece of code/application/script... can behave the way it does, it's totally useless to classify questions on SO IMO. It doesn't add any value for people searching for similar questions later.

On the other hand, there are other bad and crazy tags on SO. I can't see much harm in having them, either.

Comment: Yeah, it's not the term I'm opposed to -- I'm sure I'm guilty of dropping the term itself into question text on more than one occasion. It's the use of it as a tag. I would never think that it's a useful organizational term -- who would search for `[wtf]`?

Comment: @user0x36E0: I'll bet Alex Papadimoulis searches for that tag.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has already created the following TLAs:

- WAF (Web Application Framework)
- WCF (Windows Communication Foundation)
- WGF (Windows Graphics Foundation - DirectX)
- WIF (Windows Identity Foundation)
- WMF (Windows Metafile)
- WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation)
- WSF (Windows Script File)
- WWF (World Wrestling Federation)
- ???

I'm sure it's only a matter of time before they create the **Windows Testing Foundation (WTF)**, at which point we'll all be **really** glad that the tag still exists.

Comment: It does: *Web Template Framework* on Chromium's codebase (we can blame Google).

Comment: I *knew* Microsoft had to be behind WWF. It's all a metaphor for the computing industry, isn't it?

Comment: @mmyers: it's not a metaphor, it's a re-enactment.

Comment: @json: God help us all.

Comment: (FYI, for the .NET challenged, there really is a WWF, it's Windows Workflow Foundation. It's since been changed to just WF because the original acronym was dumb.)

Comment: @Aaron: what was dumb? The original acronym, or wrestling in general?

Comment: @John Saunders: Yes.

Comment: @Aaron: I see...

Comment: @John: OK, it wasn't "dumb", but it always gave me the giggles to hear someone talking about "W.W.F.", or even better when they tried to "say" it and it came out as "woof." Maybe I'm just immature. I'm comfortable with that.

Comment: Or they changed it for the same reason the World Wrestling Federation changed their name - the World Wildlife Fund decided they own any and all uses of WWF, regardless of industry, and in the past has successfully used the courts to enforce that.

Answer (score 0):

There were 37 questions tagged [wtf] just a few hours ago.  I retagged all but four, and Jon Seigel retagged two of those.

The [remaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752163/insanely-slow-web-site-performance-closed) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522388/stackoverflow-alerts-closed) are locked due to migration.

Comment: Seriously? did you not read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45844/is-the-tag-wtf-acceptable/45851#45851

Comment: Yes, I read it.  Did you read my comment on it? @ear